# Updating a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to update my mysql database using php. I can update it perfectly with the following:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "logintest");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

<?php

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET bot = '1' WHERE id = 9";

    if($conn -> query ($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "record updated successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Error updating record" . $conn -> error;
    }

    $conn -> close ();

?>
```

But before I update the above bot column to 1, I want to check and see if it is 0, as it can only be 0 or 1. 
To do this I done the following (see below) but it isn't working, Is it possible and or Is there a different way of doing it? All help is appreciated thanks!!

```
$sql = "SELECT bot FROM user"; // bot is the column in the table which should be 0 or 1

        if( $sql == '0') { //if its 0 i can update it

            echo 'here'; //if i get here i will update using code above
     }
```

Comment: You need to execute your query and not only store it in a variable :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to this, how would I do that? And Thank You

Comment: It's not useful to have `if (x === TRUE)` in your code. Just test using `if (x)` most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches

1. `SELECT` and `UPDATE`

   ```
   $query = "SELECT bot FROM user where id=9"
   $res = $conn->query($query);

   if ($res->num_rows == 1) {
   // it should return only one row as id is unique
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
     if($row["bot"] == 0){
           // UPDATE 
     }
   }
   ```
2. `CASE` construct

   ```
   UPDATE  user SET bot = CASE 
       WHEN bot = 0 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE bot 
       END 
   WHERE id='9'
   ```

How it works:

It updates bot value depending on returned value of matched cases. If current `bot` value is `0`, then it returns `1`, else it returns `current value` for row with `id=9`.

Advantage: Only 1 query

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "logintest");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql= "SELECT bot FROM user where columnid=value"; // change is according to your real value
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row["bot"] == 0){
            $sql = "UPDATE user SET bot = '1' WHERE id = 9";

            if($conn -> query ($sql) === TRUE){
                echo "record updated successfully";
            }else{
                echo "Error updating record" . $conn -> error;
            }
        }
    }
}

$conn -> close ();
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.